# how to pass id dynamically in jquery focus event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Can I pass the button ID dynamically?

```
$('#Button1').focus(function () {
        if (document.getElementById('HiddenVal').value != null && document.getElementById('HiddenVal').value != '') {
            $('#txtbox1').val(document.getElementById('HiddenVal').value);
            $('#Button1', window.parent.document).css("background-color", "#fcc63b");
            document.getElementById('HiddenVal').value   = '';
        }
    });
```

Here I want to pass the button ID dynamically instead of using  `$('#Button1')`.

Can I use that?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. Could you add more detail? Also, you don't need to use document.getElementById if you're using jquery. You can just use the shorthand jquery methods

Comment: ya it basically depends on where do you want to get the buttons from, you can just assign the button1 to a variable name if you don't want to use the string value directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can- place your code inside a function...and pass id as a parameter to that function - like this..

```
function dynamicId(id){ 

        newId = '#'+id
        $(newId ).focus(function () { 

        ...
        ...
        });
}
```

Comment: @Saloni-see updated answer, if still you are not clear with it let me know.

Comment: and how can i call this function?? is it in onfocus event of button??

Comment: Vivek ur code is not working properly can u explain ur code once again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code could be written as :

```
    $('#Button1').focus(function () {
        var hiddenValue = $('#HiddenVal').val();
        if (hiddenValue  != null && hiddenValue != '') {
            $('#txtbox1').val($(hiddenValue );
            $(this).css("background-color", "#fcc63b");
            $('#HiddenVal').val('');
        }
    });
```

Regards,

Max

Comment: how can you use  $(this).css("background-color", "#fcc63b"); , if op wants parent window element as a selector.

Comment: i want that button id should be pass dynamically instead of passing id itself as i want to place code in js file and call that file

Comment: sorry, i didn't catch what you want. Since Vivek answers, that's fine :)